# Javascript index out of range in a library

Tags: javascript

I am trying to adapt a Javascript library, Name That Color, to Python.

http://chir.ag/projects/ntc/ntc.js

I am confused about this block of code:

```
for(var i = 0; i < ntc.names.length; i++)
    {
      if(color == "#" + ntc.names[i][0])
        return ["#" + ntc.names[i][0], ntc.names[i][1], true];

      ndf1 = Math.pow(r - ntc.names[i][2], 2) + Math.pow(g - ntc.names[i][3], 2) + Math.pow(b - ntc.names[i][4], 2);
      ndf2 = Math.pow(h - ntc.names[i][5], 2) + Math.pow(s - ntc.names[i][6], 2) + Math.pow(l - ntc.names[i][7], 2);
      ndf = ndf1 + ndf2 * 2;
      if(df < 0 || df > ndf)
      {
        df = ndf;
        cl = i;
      }
    }
```

where this is `ntc.names`:

```
names: [
["000000", "Black"],
["000080", "Navy Blue"],
["0000C8", "Dark Blue"],
["0000FF", "Blue"],
["000741", "Stratos"],
["001B1C", "Swamp"],
["002387", "Resolution Blue"],
...
["FFFEFD", "Romance"],
["FFFF00", "Yellow"],
["FFFF66", "Laser Lemon"],
["FFFF99", "Pale Canary"],
["FFFFB4", "Portafino"],
["FFFFF0", "Ivory"],
["FFFFFF", "White"]
]
```

Aren't the calls `ntc.names[i][2]`, `ntc.names[i][3]` ... `ntc.names[i][7]` out of range of the names indicies?

How does this code work?

Comment: Have a look at the `init` method...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the `ntc.names` array is getting changed in the `init` method:

```
  ntc.names[i].push(rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2], hsl[0], hsl[1], hsl[2]);
```

So no, not out of range.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice that